# Using Visible Value option to go to next page after selection

Tags: html, html-select

I'm trying to create a type of flow using HTML for example (code at the bottom)
I select "Cisco" it goes to then next box for me to select the type, I choose "PE Routers" then to the next set of options I select the device and so on until is complete

how do I create something like that to continue? it'll be use for troubleshooting to check and verify the steps that have been completed and what to try or do next depending on the option selected.

Photo example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAgGs.png)

---

```
<label for="cars">Choose device</label><br>
<select class="detail-ta" id="detail-ta2" size="3">
   <option style="text-overflow: clip; overflow: visible; white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; white-space: pre-wrap; margin-bottom: 1px;"></option>
  <option value="Cisco">Cisco</option>
  <option value="Juniper">Juniper</option>
  <option value="Rad">Rad</option>
  <option value="Adva">Adva</option></option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label for="Cisco Device type">Choose Type</label><br>
<select class="detail-ta" id="detail-ta2" size="3">
    <option style="text-overflow: clip; overflow: visible; white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; white-space: pre-wrap; margin-bottom: 1px;">
   <option value="PE Router">PE Router</option>
  <option value="Router">Router</option>
  <option value="Switch">Switch</option>  
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label for="Cisco PE DEVICE">Choose Cisco PE device</label><br>
<select class="detail-ta" id="detail-ta2" size="4">
    <option style="text-overflow: clip; overflow: visible; white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; white-space: pre-wrap; margin-bottom: 1px;">
   <option value="9000">Cisco ASR 9000</option>
  <option value="1000">Cisco ASR 1000</option>
  <option value="920">Cisco ASR 920</option>
    <option value="560">NCS 560</option>  
</select>
```

I was wanting it to go to the step as an option is selected
e.g. "Yes" would go the next option

photo example attached (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aWCd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript.

First, you should set special IDs for the selected boxes; then this code will work:

```
<script>
    var SelectBox1 = document.getElementById("detail-ta2");
    var SelectBox2 = document.getElementById("detail-ta3");
    var SelectBox3 = document.getElementById("detail-ta4");
    SelectBox1.addEventListener("change", () => {
        if(SelectBox1?.value && SelectBox1.value != ''){
            SelectBox2.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            SelectBox2.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    SelectBox2.addEventListener("change", () => {
        if(SelectBox2?.value && SelectBox1.value != ''){
            SelectBox3.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            SelectBox3.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```